# OpenVPN - No internet after connection

Tags: linux, centos, openvpn, centos8

I have a OpenVPN Server on a CentOS 8 machine that has firewalld and nftables. I have set up OpenVPN with this script:

https://github.com/angristan/openvpn-install

The OpenVPN Client is a Windows 10 machine.

I have following problem:
As soon as I connect, no connection to the internet can be made. Traceroute shows that I reach my vpn server:

```
> tracert 1.1

Routenverfolgung zu 1.0.0.1 über maximal 30 Hops

  1   185 ms   185 ms   185 ms  10.8.0.1
  2     *        *        *     Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
  3     *        *        *     Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
  4     *        *        *     Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
  5     *        *        *     Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
  6     *        *        *     Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
```

However, after the first hop, nothing happens.

The CentOS 8 machine has a connection of course and can reach 1.1 (1.0.0.1) easily:

```
~# ping 1.1
PING 1.1 (1.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 1.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=27.10 ms
64 bytes from 1.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=28.5 ms
```

When I do "tcpdump -i tun0" on my CentOS 8 machine, I can see that 10.8.0.2 (the Windows 10 Client) is trying to reach 1.0.0.1 with ICMP. However, only requests, no ICMP replies.

I can also see that a lot of TCP retransmissions are happening when I run Wireshark on the Windows 10 Client after some time, which apparently comes from DNS requests? See screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DenXT.png

The output of firewall-cmd --list-all is as follows:

```
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: venet0
  sources:
  services:
  ports: 80/tcp 443/tcp 21/tcp 25/tcp 53/tcp 53/udp 110/tcp 143/tcp 465/tcp 587/tcp 993/tcp 995/tcp 7080/tcp 7081/tcp 8443/tcp 8447/tcp 8880/tcp 49152-65535/tcp 10022/tcp 10022/udp
  protocols:
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
        rule family="ipv4" source address="10.8.0.0/24" masquerade
```

Sensitive output is removed.

If anyone can point me in a right direction how to debug this I would be very thankful.